# Ubuntu dpkg: error processing package (after apt-get upgrade)

Tags: python, dpkg

I recently deleted my all python files from dpkg info to solve this but that didn't work, even damaged. Then after installing ubuntu-desktop, again facing with same issue.

```
[root@nar-ubuntu ~]$ apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  dmsetup libdevmapper1.02.1
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 202 kB/326 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://am.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libdevmapper1.02.1 amd64 2:1.02.145-4.1ubuntu3.18.04.2 [127 kB]
75% [Working]                               
Get:2 http://am.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 dmsetup amd64 2:1.02.145-4.1ubuntu3.18.04.2 [74.5 kB]
Fetched 202 kB in 0s (903 kB/s)   
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python-apt-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-cryptography' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python-pip-whl' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-yaml' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-speechd' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-distro-info' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-pil:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-cups' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3.6' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-apt' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-dbus' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-rfc3339' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-pyatspi' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-cffi-backend' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-olefile' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-keyring' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-brlapi' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-mako' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-crypto' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-requests-unixsocket' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-simplejson' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-idna' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-xdg' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-update-manager' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-keyrings.alt' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-six' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-oauth' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3.6-minimal' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-pymacaroons' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-certifi' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-wadllib' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-zope.interface' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-gi-cairo' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-pkg-resources' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-gi' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-apport' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-markupsafe' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-lazr.restfulclient' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-defer' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-problem-report' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-asn1crypto' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-reportlab' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-macaroonbakery' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-protobuf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-debconf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-pexpect' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-chardet' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-aptdaemon' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-systemd' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-minimal' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-httplib2' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-requests' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-nacl' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-cupshelpers' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-software-properties' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-urllib3' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-reportlab-accel:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-cairo:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3.6-dev' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-launchpadlib' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-secretstorage' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-ptyprocess' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-tz' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-debian' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-louis' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-distupgrade' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python2.7-minimal' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-dateutil' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-xkit' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python-talloc' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-lazr.uri' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 250868 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libdevmapper1.02.1_2%3a1.02.145-4.1ubuntu3.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdevmapper1.02.1:amd64 (2:1.02.145-4.1ubuntu3.18.04.2) over (2:1.02.145-4.1ubuntu3.18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../dmsetup_2%3a1.02.145-4.1ubuntu3.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dmsetup (2:1.02.145-4.1ubuntu3.18.04.2) over (2:1.02.145-4.1ubuntu3.18.04.1) ...
Setting up python2.7 (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.2) ...
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
/usr/bin/python2.7: can't open file '/usr/lib/python2.7/py_compile.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package python2.7 (--configure):
 installed python2.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Setting up libdevmapper1.02.1:amd64 (2:1.02.145-4.1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Setting up python-minimal (2.7.15~rc1-1) ...
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
dpkg: error processing package python-minimal (--configure):
 installed python-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: error processing package apport (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Setting up dmsetup (2:1.02.145-4.1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.9) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-37-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python2.7
 python-minimal
 apport
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: @A.B I've tried it so many times and does'nt help me. I'll give it a shot one more time, thanks though.

Comment: Your issue is that python is missing so you deleted all python files to solve that issue?

Comment: @A.B `E: Internal Error, No file name for python-minimal:amd64` how can I reinstall python-minimal?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, if you delete the files that dpkg was suppose to handle, it will report an error.  Generally you shouldn't delete files meant to be handled by the package manager.

Reinstall the packages and then uninstall them properly using apt, dpkg or you're favorite front-end and you will be good.

Worst case, do a clean reinstall of your system.  Yes, you can keep user data across reinstalls.

As a note, if you can't uninstall something because of dependencies, that means you likely need it and shouldn't uninstall it.  Don't manually uninstall things in the future.  The most you should do is add a few missing links or edit a few config files.

Comment: `E: Internal Error, No file name for python-minimal:amd64` how can I reinstall python-minimal?

Comment: Use apt to install from repositories not dpkg.   Dpkg is individual packages, not repositories.

There is a way to install from repository using dpkg, but it's not pretty.   Use apt or a front end.